# Throttling Test Using Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, throttling, jmeter-5.0

I am learning **Jmeter** tool for `load & perfomace testing` and while testing a **Geoserver rest api** I am unable to set up configuration for throttling limit test .

Lets have an example:

I need to test throttling limit of Rest API can accept the request `500 requests/second`

If user send request more than 500 requests let say `501 requests/second` script should throw the error `code 429 too many requests.`

While doing some research I found that **Synchronizing Timer** can be used.However couldn't able to manage.

My Question is how can I achieve that Using **Jemeter**?
Any help/guidance will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

With the Synchronizing Timer you cannot achieve 500 requests per second, you can achieve 500 requests **at the same moment**

If you need to send X requests per second it would be better idea to go for [Constant Throughput Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Constant_Throughput_Timer) or [Throughput Shaping Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-throughput-shaping-timer-plugin/), this way you can control how many requests per second JMeter will be sending and define pass/fail criteria for your test plan via [Assertions](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#assertion) basing on the current throughput

Comment: Thanks for your response.Could you please elaborate how can I achieve the error code 429 if I send 501 requests/second using Jmeter. I am new to load testing.